# React Search Box working well while adding text but not working in backward direction (when deleting some text by backspace)-ReactJS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Demo Project - [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5403m1n20n). I am working with React Table. I am trying to create a custom box which can filter only the first column - firstName. Based on the first column search the corresponding rows of other columns will be displayed.

Filter work perfectly fine when we are adding characters, but once we start deleting characters filtering does not happen [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5403m1n20n)

This is main Code (Parent Page)

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TypeChecker from "typeco";
// import matchSorter from "match-sorter";
import SearchField from "./SearchField";
import "./App.css";

import Child from "./Child/Child";
import jsondata from "./sample";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      // data: makeData(),
      data: jsondata,
      dataDefault: jsondata,
      basicExampleList: jsondata,
      filtered: [],
      select2: null,
      select3: null,
      childOpen: false
    };
    this.openChild = this.openChild.bind(this);
    this.applyFilter = this.applyFilter.bind(this);
    this.showDefaultView = this.showDefaultView.bind(this);
    this.onBasicExampleChange = this.onBasicExampleChange.bind(this);
    this.onEnterExample = this.onEnterExample.bind(this);
    this.onSearchClickExample = this.onSearchClickExample.bind(this);
    this.getMatchedList = this.getMatchedList.bind(this);
  }

  getMatchedList(searchText) {
    console.log("getMatchedList entered");
    console.log("the search text is " + searchText);
    const exampleList = this.state.basicExampleList;
    if (TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText)) {
      console.log(
        "if block of getMatchedList - > TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText) " +
          TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText)
      );
      this.setState({ basicExampleList: exampleList });
      return this.state.basicExampleList;
    }
    if (!TypeChecker.isEmpty(searchText)) {
      console.log("if block of getMatchedList is not entered ");
      return exampleList.filter(
        item =>
          item.firstName.includes(searchText) ||
          item.firstName.includes(searchText)
      );
    }
  }

  onBasicExampleChange(value) {
    console.log("onchange entered");
    console.log(" the value is " + value);
    this.setState({
      basicExampleList: this.getMatchedList(value)
    });
  }

  onEnterExample(value) {
    this.setState({
      basicExampleList: this.getMatchedList(value)
    });
  }

  onSearchClickExample(value) {
    this.setState({
      basicExampleList: this.getMatchedList(value)
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filtered) {
    console.log("Entering Apply Filter Function of Parent");
    console.log("The filtered data in parent " + JSON.stringify(filtered));
    const currentStateChild = this.state.childOpen;
    this.setState(
      {
        childOpen: !currentStateChild
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Child is opened " + this.state.childOpen);
      }
    );
    const filterArray = filtered;
    const apidata = this.state.data;
    let filteredData = apidata.filter((
      item // filter jsondata
    ) =>
      filterArray.every((
        f // so every member of filter array
      ) => f.value.includes(item[f.id]))
    ); // has a corresponding item[id] in value

    console.log("The filtered rows are " + JSON.stringify(filteredData));
    this.setState(
      {
        data: filteredData
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Manipulated rows " + this.state.data);
      }
    );
  }

  openChild() {
    const currentStateChild = this.state.childOpen;
    this.setState(
      {
        childOpen: !currentStateChild
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Child is opened " + this.state.childOpen);
      }
    );
  }

  showDefaultView() {
    const defaultDataParent = this.state.dataDefault;
    this.setState(
      {
        data: defaultDataParent
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Default rows " + this.state.data);
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="clickMeToOpenChild" onClick={this.openChild}>
          {" "}
          Click Me to Open Child
        </div>
        <div className="clickMeToGetDefaultView" onClick={this.showDefaultView}>
          {" "}
          Click Me to show Default View
        </div>
        <br />
        <SearchField
          placeholder="Search item"
          onChange={this.onBasicExampleChange}
          onEnter={this.onEnterExample}
          onSearchClick={this.onSearchClickExample}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <ReactTable
          data={this.state.basicExampleList}
          filterable
          filtered={this.state.filtered}
          onFilteredChange={(filtered, column, value) => {
            this.onFilteredChangeCustom(value, column.id || column.accessor);
          }}
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row, column) => {
            const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
            if (typeof filter.value === "object") {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? filter.value.indexOf(row[id]) > -1
                : true;
            } else {
              return row[id] !== undefined
                ? String(row[id]).indexOf(filter.value) > -1
                : true;
            }
          }}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        {this.state.childOpen && (
          <Child data={data} applyFilter={this.applyFilter} />
        )}
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Kindly help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Filtering doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: The code for `lastName.includes()` was missing for me. From the code, it looks like you're writing the filtered list to the actual list. So, if there's no results, then the actual list gets reset to nothing.

Comment: @Colin It is a typo, check the search box, not filtering

Comment: @Colin I want to search box to only filter from firstName, no need of search box filtering column 2(lastName)

Comment: Okay, well the issue is you're replacing the actual data with the filtered data.

Comment: @Colin Can you fork and edit to make it work?

Comment: @Colin I want to make the search box work for firstName field only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that you were overwriting the real data, so it was ending up empty if you did a search with no results.

Fixed code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n02qoylj6m).

Comment: Both demos are not working. No filtering is happening. It seems you have removed 3 functions

Comment: Weird, happens sometimes when you get a cached version. Will fix.

Comment: possible issue with this line - this.setState({ filtered: res });. There is no state variables called filtered

Comment: I don't think so, it filters fine for me. Here's another version: https://codesandbox.io/s/6xy8o98033.

Comment: Can you do me one favor? Can you kindly include two fields in filter - both firstName and lastName. No need of filter in age

Comment: Just change it to use: `return (
          item.firstName.includes(searchText) ||
          item.lastName.includes(searchText)
        );`

Comment: I have the same issue. I did like how you mentioned. but that does not work for me. it would be great if you guide me throught it.
here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233084/search-does-not-give-the-required-result-of-searched-value-reactjs-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry If my solution does not work, for me it was duplicate data was filtering. So if you can make sure that the array for filter does not have duplicate data

Comment: this looks like a comment at most

Comment: Sorry but i do not have enough reputations to comment!