# 'SEARCH' does not give the required result of searched value - REACTJS, mongodb, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have table containing `Title`, `Sub-Title` and `Count`. `sub-title` is the child of `title`.So, in the collection of `title`, `objectId` of `sub-title` is saved.

Below is the screenshot of the table.[image]

If I try to search a particular ***title*** say ***Fruits*** I get the table where the ***title*** is ***Fruits***.

[image]

Now suppose say I try searching with ***Sub-Title*** and search ***apple*** I do not get result containing only ***apple*** or any row where ***apple*** is present. Instead, I get all the data of that ***title*** as well along with the searched data.

[image]

[image]

Below is the code:

`titleSubTitle.js`

```
class titleSubTitle extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { title: "", subtitle: "", filter: {} };
  }
  fetch = () => {
    let subtitle = [];
    let subtitleIds = [];
    this.props.data.map((title) => {
      subtitle.push(
        title.children.find((subtitle) =>
          subtitle.name.includes(this.state.subtitle)
        )
      );
    });
    subtitle.forEach((element) => {
      if (element && element._id) {
        subtitleIds.push(element._id);
      }
    });

    let data = {
      title: this.state.title,
      subtitle: subtitleIds,
    };
    this.filteringData(data);
  };

  filteringData = async (data) => {
    await this.setState({ filter: data });
    this.getData();
  };

  getData = async () => {
    let data = {
      data: {
        title:
          this.state.filter && this.state.filter.title
            ? this.state.filter.title
            : null,
        subtitle:
          this.state.filter && this.state.filter.subtitle
            ? this.state.filter.subtitle
            : null,
      },
    };
    await this.props.getSequence(data);
  };

    handleFilterChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      
        <TextField
          label="Title"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
        />
        <TextField
          label="Sub-Title"
          value={this.state.subtitle}
          onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
        />
        <Button type="submit" onClick={this.fetch}>
          Search
        </Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Below is the back-end code:

```
getSequence: async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let query = {
            type: 'Title'
        };
        if (req.query.title) {
            query.titlename = new RegExp(req.query.title, 'i')
        }
        if (req.query.subtitle) {
            query.subtitlename = { $in: req.query.subtitle }
        }
        let sequence= await titlesubtitle.find(query);    
        let dataList = await titlesubtitle.find(query);

        let count = await titlesubtitle.find(query).countDocuments();
        let response = {
            data: sequence,
            totalCount: count,
            dataList : dataList 
        }
        return res.send(response);
    } catch (error){
        return res.send('Error');
    }
}
```

**So, I'll explain what I want the result as again.**

Upon search of ***sub-title*** say ***apple*** I want the table to show all the records where only ***apple*** is present. No extra records to be shown of other *sub-title*.

Upon search of ***title*** as ***Fruits*** and ***sub-title*** as ***pear***, I want only **1** record which is obvious as the result.

If I search for a record that is **not present** then the table should be **empty**. This should **apply to all the combinations**.

I cannot figure where I am going wrong. Can anyone help me out with this please.

Comment: The provided code snippet does not have the method definition for `handleFilterChange`.
Also, as a convention, the class name should be in Pascal case not camelCase.

Comment: class name being camelCase is not the cause of the error.

Comment: And handlefilterchange is just an event handler, which just changes the event. That does not affect the code otherwise @vishwasmeshram

Comment: The `handlefilterchange` should be updating your state, which is used in the `fetch` method else `fetch` method will always have an empty string for `this.state.subtitle`.

Comment: yes. Have edited the question

Comment: `TextField` component does not have `name` props, so it will still not update your state as you expect. Try debugging the value of `data` before `await this.props.getSequence(data);` 

Also, it would be helpful if you provide the minimal code on `codesandbox`, which can be used to find out the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237238/discussion-between-vishwas-meshram-and-itidi).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which mongodb version you are using but you can write your query something like this

```
$or: [
       { title: { $regex: search_text, $options: 'i' } },
       { subtitle: { $regex: search_text, $options: 'i' } }
  ]
```

This will search through your table and find specific results for your search text (even partial matches)